# Packer "No valid credential sources found for AWS builder" using -var or static credentials

Tags: packer

I am trying to build a basic ami image using packer, I embed my access_key and secret-key but I still get the title error.

My packer template file:

```
{
    "builders": [{
        "name": "packer-ex",
        "type": "amazon-ebs",
        "access_key": "",
        "secret_key": "",
        "region": "us-west-2",
        "source_ami_filter": {
            "filters": {
                "virtualization-type": "hvm",
                "name": "ubuntu/images/*ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-*",
                "root-device-type": "ebs"
            },
            "owners": ["099720109477"],
            "most_recent": true
       },
        "instance_type": "t2.micro",
        "ssh_username": "ubuntu",
        "ami_name": "packer-example {{timestamp}}"
    }],
    "provisioners": [{
        "type": "shell",
        "inline":[
            "sleep 30",
            "sudo apt-get update",
            "sudo apt-get install -y apache2",
            "sudo apt-get install mysql",
            "sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql",
            "sudo systemctl restart apache2"
        ]
     }]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to configure a profile with credentials ans  the correct access rights (`aws --profile=<profile> configure`) and then use that when running Packer by explicitly setting the environment variable `AWS_PROFILE`. I.e. `AWS_PROFILE=<profile> packer build template.json`